# Representatives of Quotient Group of Galois Groups

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory, galois-extensions

Let $M:L:K$ be normal and seperable field extensions, then we know by the fundamental theorem of Galois theory that
$$
\frac{\text{Gal}(M:K)}{\text{Gal}(M:L)} \cong \text{Gal}(L:K)
$$

I was wondering if the following is true

Let us fix a basis for $M$: $x = \sum_i x_i\alpha_i \quad \forall x\in M$.

Can $\frac{\text{Gal}(M:K)}{\text{Gal(M:L)}}$ be represented by the set

$$
g\in \text{Aut}(M): g(\alpha_i)=
\begin{cases} 
g(\alpha_i) & \forall \alpha_i \in L \\ 
\alpha_i & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

I suppose the answer is yes, because $g$ permutes the different $\alpha_i$ and we can always negate the permutation on the $\alpha_i$ outside $L$ by an element $h\in \text{Gal(M:L)}$.

Is this reasoning correct?